# How to solve the following heat equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, heat-equation

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, $u=u(r,t)$, $t$ for time, $r$ for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ on (0, +\infty)

The equations are given as
$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\partial_t u=\Delta u\\
u(R,t) = c\\
u(r,0) = c\\
u_r(r_0,t)=f(t)
\end{array}
\right.$

in which $c,0<r_0<R$ are all constants.

Since the equations are not homogeneous, I failed to apply method of separation of variables, the heat source is also not on the boundary. I don't know which method works now, could someone help me?

Comment: I think the second line should instead read $u(r,0)=c$ ?

Comment: Also I am confused - are you solving the heat equation in the domain $r_0<r<R$? Or $0<r<r_0$ ? If so what is the relevance of $R$?

Comment: @K.defaoite I'm sorry the third line is wrong, I've corrected it.

Comment: @K.defaoite the domain is (0, R)

Comment: Hint: express $\Delta$ in polar coordinates.